# What is a "theme" in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, lxde, theme, appearance

I have only used LXDE and Xfce. While in LXDE windows styles (decorations) and general appearance themes ("Widgets" in LXDE) can be clearly differentiated when searched on the internet, for Xfce they are found together (http://xfce-look.org and other sites like that) and cannot be known as what they really are until installed.

For example, in a player in Xfce:

[image]

the window "theme" is responsible only for a small part of the appearance, namely the upper buttons, while the rest (excepting icons) is determined by a different package that is also called "theme", and which changes also the appearance of the panel.

What is the proper name to use for one and the other?

Is there a website where these two a clearly differentiated? I'm tired of searching for a good Xfce (general appearance) theme only to find it under "Window manager".